# Why does different search bar output merge together

Tags: javascript, html, web, search, search-engine

i'm working on a website were the search bar is bugged. I can't find a solution and hope some of you guys know the solution. This is a video about my problem. The video shows how i can type in three different search bars but the suggestions always goes in the bottom  element even though on my Javascript it's clearly "talking" to another  element with another id: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhi3t2mqHuo
This is the script for the bottom search bar (the same for both the other search bars instead it's different id's called on the `<input>` and the `<ul>` elements.

```
<form method="POST" class="search-bar step-search-bar">
    <input id="how-searchTerm" class="search-bar-input step-search-bar-input" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="search-bar-btn step-search-bar-btn" type="submit" value="Search"></input>
    <ul id="how-quickipedia_output"></ul>
    <script>
        var yb = { id : function(str){return document.getElementById(str)} };

        yb.id('how-searchTerm').focus();

        var tag = '';

        yb.id('how-searchTerm').onkeyup = function(e){
             if(!e.keyCode.toString().match(/^(37|38|39|40|13|16|17|18|224)$/)){
                   if(tag!==''){ document.body.removeChild(tag); }

                   tag = document.createElement('script');
                   var term = yb.id('how-searchTerm').value;

                   tag.src = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=10&format=json&callback=ybComplete&search='+term;
                   document.body.appendChild(tag);
             }
        };

        var ybComplete = function(data){
             yb.id('how-quickipedia_output').innerHTML = '';
                  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
                       if(data[1][i]){
                           yb.id('how-quickipedia_output').innerHTML += '<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data[1][i] + '" target="_blank">' + data[1][i] + '</a>' + data[2][i] + '</li>';
                       }
                  }
             };
      </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you reuse the function `ybComplete` for all the search bars? You need unique callback names.

Comment: Thanks alot, I made it work, if anyone else has the same problem just change the ybComplete variable AND the ybComplete inside the tag.src link to the same as the variable. Thanks again Barmar :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem that I found thanks to Barmar is to change the "ybComplete" variable to a completly new variable on all your scripts that looks like this. Then also change the "ybComplete" text in the tag.src link to the same as your new variable name.